# Java label irregularity (possible bug?)

Tags: java, label, java-8, standards

If we look at the [Java standard](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/jls8.pdf) §14.7, we see that statements may have label prefixes, e.g.:

> *LabeledStatement:*
>
> *Identifier : Statement*

In theory, a label should be able to label any succeeding statement. So, for example, the following compiles accordingly:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    hello:
        return;
    }

}
```

Intuitively, this also compiles:

```
public class Test {
    int i;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test t = new Test();
    label:
        t.i = 2;        
    }
}
```

But the following does **not** compile:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    oops:
        int k = 3;  
    }
}
```

Even though this does (note the scoped brackets):

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    oops:
        {
            int k = 3;
        }
    }
}
```

So the question hinges on whether or not declarations are statements. According to the standard (and the [online documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/expressions.html)):

> In addition to expression statements, there are two other kinds of statements: declaration statements and control flow statements. A declaration statement declares a variable.

I've noticed this behavior in Java 7 and 8 on both OSX as well as Windows. Is this a bug or am I misunderstanding the standard?

Comment: Interesting. What error message does the compiler give?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The expression

```
int k = 3;
```

is a [local variable declaration statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.4).

The [`statement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-Statement) used in the syntax of a label statement

> `LabeledStatement`:
>
> `Identifier` : [`Statement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-Statement)

does not contain local variable declaration statements. You therefore can't use them within a labeled statement directly.

Local variable declaration statements can be used within [blocks](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-Block) which can be used within labeled statements.